# Faster numpy cartesian to spherical coordinate conversion?

Tags: python, numpy, coordinate

I have an array of 3 million data points from a 3-axiz accellerometer (XYZ), and I want to add 3 columns to the array containing the equivalent spherical coordinates (r, theta, phi).  The following code works, but seems way too slow.  How can I do better?

```
import numpy as np
import math as m

def cart2sph(x,y,z):
    XsqPlusYsq = x**2 + y**2
    r = m.sqrt(XsqPlusYsq + z**2)               # r
    elev = m.atan2(z,m.sqrt(XsqPlusYsq))     # theta
    az = m.atan2(y,x)                           # phi
    return r, elev, az

def cart2sphA(pts):
    return np.array([cart2sph(x,y,z) for x,y,z in pts])

def appendSpherical(xyz):
    np.hstack((xyz, cart2sphA(xyz)))
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is similar to [Justin Peel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116658/faster-numpy-cartesian-to-spherical-coordinate-conversion/4116803#4116803)'s answer, but using just `numpy` and taking advantage of its built-in vectorization:

```
import numpy as np

def appendSpherical_np(xyz):
    ptsnew = np.hstack((xyz, np.zeros(xyz.shape)))
    xy = xyz[:,0]**2 + xyz[:,1]**2
    ptsnew[:,3] = np.sqrt(xy + xyz[:,2]**2)
    ptsnew[:,4] = np.arctan2(np.sqrt(xy), xyz[:,2]) # for elevation angle defined from Z-axis down
    #ptsnew[:,4] = np.arctan2(xyz[:,2], np.sqrt(xy)) # for elevation angle defined from XY-plane up
    ptsnew[:,5] = np.arctan2(xyz[:,1], xyz[:,0])
    return ptsnew
```

Note that, as suggested in the comments, I've **changed the definition of elevation angle** from your original function.  On my machine, testing with `pts = np.random.rand(3000000, 3)`, the time went from 76 seconds to 3.3 seconds.  I don't have Cython so I wasn't able to compare the timing with that solution.

Comment: Great job, my Cython solution is only a little bit faster (1.23 seconds vs. 1.54 seconds on my machine). For some reason, I didn't see the vectorized arctan2 function when I looked for doing it straight with numpy. +1

Comment: Anon suggested `ptsnew[:,4] = np.arctan2(np.sqrt(xy),xyz[:,2])`

Comment: I think this implementation might be slightly slower than the cpython one because your are using `zeros()` in the first line, which requires that huge block (the right hand half of the output) to be needlessly traversed twice, once to fill it with zeros and once to fill it with the real data. Instead you should allocate the entire Nx6 array with `np.empty()` and fill the two halfs of it using slicing

Answer (score 16):

Here's a quick Cython code that I wrote up for this:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    long double sqrt(long double xx)
    long double atan2(long double a, double b)

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def appendSpherical(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] xyz):
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] pts = np.empty((xyz.shape[0],6))
    cdef long double XsqPlusYsq
    for i in xrange(xyz.shape[0]):
        pts[i,0] = xyz[i,0]
        pts[i,1] = xyz[i,1]
        pts[i,2] = xyz[i,2]
        XsqPlusYsq = xyz[i,0]**2 + xyz[i,1]**2
        pts[i,3] = sqrt(XsqPlusYsq + xyz[i,2]**2)
        pts[i,4] = atan2(xyz[i,2],sqrt(XsqPlusYsq))
        pts[i,5] = atan2(xyz[i,1],xyz[i,0])
    return pts
```

It took the time down from 62.4 seconds to 1.22 seconds using 3,000,000 points for me. That's not too shabby. I'm sure there are some other improvements that can be made.

Comment: Was my original code (in the question) wrong?  Or are you talking about the other answer(s)?

Answer (score 15):

! There is an error still in all the code above.. and this is a top Google result..
TLDR:
I have tested this with VPython, using atan2 for theta (elev) is wrong, use
acos! It is correct for phi (azim).
I recommend the sympy1.0 acos function (it does not even complain about acos(z/r) with r = 0 ) .

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html

If we convert that to the physics system (r, theta, phi) = (r, elev, azimuth) we have:

```
r = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)
phi = atan2(y,x)
theta = acos(z,r)
```

Non optimized but **correct** code for right-handed physics system:

```
from sympy import *
def asCartesian(rthetaphi):
    #takes list rthetaphi (single coord)
    r       = rthetaphi[0]
    theta   = rthetaphi[1]* pi/180 # to radian
    phi     = rthetaphi[2]* pi/180
    x = r * sin( theta ) * cos( phi )
    y = r * sin( theta ) * sin( phi )
    z = r * cos( theta )
    return [x,y,z]

def asSpherical(xyz):
    #takes list xyz (single coord)
    x       = xyz[0]
    y       = xyz[1]
    z       = xyz[2]
    r       =  sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)
    theta   =  acos(z/r)*180/ pi #to degrees
    phi     =  atan2(y,x)*180/ pi
    return [r,theta,phi]
```

you can test it yourself with a function like:

```
test = asCartesian(asSpherical([-2.13091326,-0.0058279,0.83697319]))
```

some other test data for some quadrants:

```
[[ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [-2.13091326 -0.0058279   0.83697319]
 [ 1.82172775  1.15959835  1.09232283]
 [ 1.47554111 -0.14483833 -1.80804324]
 [-1.13940573 -1.45129967 -1.30132008]
 [ 0.33530045 -1.47780466  1.6384716 ]
 [-0.51094007  1.80408573 -2.12652707]]
```

I used VPython additionally to easily visualize vectors:

```
test   = v.arrow(pos = (0,0,0), axis = vis_ori_ALA , shaftwidth=0.05, color=v.color.red)
```

Comment: It is not an error. Both formulas are correct. Note the arguments of the arctan and arccos functions in both cases.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if the library changed but your method names are all incorrect, still I up-voted your answer as aside from the mistakes it's fairly good.

Comment: Well, nevertheless, this answer has saved me from an impasse.

Answer (score 9):

To complete the previous answers, here is a [Numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) implementation (with a possible fallback to Numpy),

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import arctan2, sqrt
import numexpr as ne

def cart2sph(x,y,z, ceval=ne.evaluate):
    """ x, y, z :  ndarray coordinates
        ceval: backend to use: 
              - eval :  pure Numpy
              - numexpr.evaluate:  Numexpr """
    azimuth = ceval('arctan2(y,x)')
    xy2 = ceval('x**2 + y**2')
    elevation = ceval('arctan2(z, sqrt(xy2))')
    r = eval('sqrt(xy2 + z**2)')
    return azimuth, elevation, r
```

For large array sizes, this allows a factor of 2 speed up compared to pure a Numpy implementation, and would be comparable to C or Cython speeds. The present numpy solution (when used with the `ceval=eval` argument) is also 25% faster than the `appendSpherical_np` function in the [@mtrw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116899/1791279) answer for large array sizes,

```
In [1]: xyz = np.random.rand(3000000,3)
   ...: x,y,z = xyz.T
In [2]: %timeit -n 1 appendSpherical_np(xyz)
1 loops, best of 3: 397 ms per loop
In [3]: %timeit -n 1 cart2sph(x,y,z, ceval=eval)
1 loops, best of 3: 280 ms per loop
In [4]: %timeit -n 1 cart2sph(x,y,z, ceval=ne.evaluate)
1 loops, best of 3: 145 ms per loop
```

although for smaller sizes, `appendSpherical_np` is actually faster,

```
In [5]: xyz = np.random.rand(3000,3)
...: x,y,z = xyz.T
In [6]: %timeit -n 1 appendSpherical_np(xyz)
1 loops, best of 3: 206 µs per loop
In [7]: %timeit -n 1 cart2sph(x,y,z, ceval=eval)
1 loops, best of 3: 261 µs per loop
In [8]: %timeit -n 1 cart2sph(x,y,z, ceval=ne.evaluate)
1 loops, best of 3: 271 µs per loop
```

Comment: I was unaware of numexpr.  My long-term hope is to eventually switch to pypy when numpypy can do all I need, so a "pure Python" solution is preferred.  While this is 2.7x faster than appendSpherical_np(), appendSpherical_np() itself provided the 50x improvement I was looking for without needing another package.  But still, you met the challenge, so +1 to you!

Comment: i tried the various methods and this one is by far the fastest for large datasets

Answer (score 4):

Octave has some built-in functionality for coordinate transformations that can be accessed with the package oct2py to convert numpy arrays in Cartesian coordinates to spherical or polar coordinates (and back):

```
from oct2py import octave
xyz = np.random.rand(3000000,3)
%timeit thetaphir = octave.cart2sph(xyz)

724 ms ± 206 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

I base my code on mrtw's answer - I added axis support, the reverse function and base it off a 3-tuple shape:

```py
def from_xyz(xyz, axis=-1):
    x, y, z = np.moveaxis(xyz, axis, 0)

    lea = np.empty_like(xyz)

    pre_selector = ((slice(None),) * lea.ndim)[:axis]

    xy_sq = x ** 2 + y ** 2
    lea[(*pre_selector, 0)] = np.sqrt(xy_sq + z ** 2)
    lea[(*pre_selector, 1)] = np.arctan2(np.sqrt(xy_sq), z)
    lea[(*pre_selector, 2)] = np.arctan2(y, x)

    return lea


def to_xyz(lea, axis=-1):
    l, e, a = np.moveaxis(lea, axis, 0)

    xyz = np.empty_like(lea)

    pre_selector = ((slice(None),) * xyz.ndim)[:axis]

    xyz[(*pre_selector, 0)] = l * np.sin(e) * np.cos(a)
    xyz[(*pre_selector, 1)] = l * np.sin(e) * np.sin(a)
    xyz[(*pre_selector, 2)] = l * np.cos(e)

    return xyz
```

Comment: Line 6 has an error.  `spherical.ndim` should be `lea.ndim`.