# How can I interpolate array from spherical to cartesian coordinates with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array of density values in spherical coordinates.  More specifically I have an array called density with shape (180,200,200).  I also have an array called r_coord, theta_coord and phi_coord also with shape (180,200,200) being the spherical coordinates for the density array.

I would like to map this density to cartesian coordinates using python.  I will need therefore a new density2 which is interpolated over cartesian coordinates x_coord, y_coord and z_coord.  I found scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates which looks promising but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116658/faster-numpy-cartesian-to-spherical-coordinate-conversion for possible pointers on how to do this.

Comment: Interpolation here is the tricky part, not the coordinate transformation (which is what the comment above refers to).  imho, OP is correct to suggest on of the nd interpolation routines.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
import scipy.interpolate
rflat=scipy.array( r_coord.flat )
tflat=scipy.array( theta_coord.flat )
pflat=scipy.array( phi_coord.flat )
coordpoints=scipy.concatenate( [ rflat[:, scipy.newaxis], tflat[:,scipy.newaxis], pflat[:,scipy.newaxis] ] , axis=1 )
rtpinterpolator=scipy.interpolate.linearNDInterpolate( coordppoints, density.flat )    

def xyz2rtp( x,y,z):
     r=scipy.sqrt( x**2+y**2+z**2)
     t=scipy.acos( z/r )
     p=scipy.atan2( y, x )
     return (r,t,p)

# now you can get the interpolated value for any (x,y,z) coordinate you want.
val=rtpinterpolator( xyz2rtp( x,y,z) )
```

Key points:

- Use the existing scipy multi-dimensional interpolation,
- convert the `xyz` coordinates to `rtp` when you pass it in to the interpolator.