# Computing diameter-lines of a 3D spherical mask

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, 3d, geometry

#### Background

For an algorithm I'm working on, I currently use a 3D sphere as binary mask, with a `NxNxN` array having voxels in a sphere of radius  `N//2`  as `True`. Further processing does computation for each voxel set as `True`.

It proved computationally intensive for my specific task as `N` grew large =  O(N^3), so I now want to reduce my binary mask to a subsample of lines radiating from array center within radius.

#### Objective

I want a 3D binary mask of the lines in gray in the image.

[image: Half-lines]

To have a bit of control over the number of voxels, I would have a parameter (say `l`) regulating the number of lines sampled in each 2D circle, and maybe a second one (`k` ?) for the number of z-rotation.

#### What I tried

I am using numpy and scipy, and I thought that I could use the [scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html) method to rotate a single line around on a plane, then use that complete 2D mask to rotate around the z-axis.
This proved difficult, as interpolate uses some deep magic regarding splines that discard my True values on rotation.

I am thinking that I could compute mathematically which voxel should be set to True by following some line-equations, but I'm at a loss to find them.

Any idea how to get there ?

#### Update : Solution !

Thanks to jkalden who helped me think this through and gave code samples, I have this :

`rmax` is radius of sphere, `n_theta` and `n_phi` the number of polar and azimutal lines to use.

```
out_mask = np.zeros((rmax*2,) * 3, dtype=bool)

# for each phi = one circle in azimutal circles
for phi in np.linspace(0, np.deg2rad(360), n_phi,endpoint=False):
    # for all lines in polar circle of this azimutal circle
    for theta in np.linspace(0, np.deg2rad(360), n_theta,endpoint=False):
        # for all distances (0-rmax) in these lines
        for r in range(rmax):

        coords = spherical_to_cartesian([r, theta, phi]) + rmax
        out_mask[tuple(coords)] = True
```

With the `spherical_to_cartesian` from [this code sample](http://svn.gna.org/svn/relax/tags/1.3.16/maths_fns/coord_transform.py).

Which gives me this (with `rmax = 50` and `n_theta = n_phi = 8`) :

[image: Irised !]
(Center area tuned out of my function by choice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose to change the coordinate system to [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). Thus, you will choose your 2D circle by an azimuthal angle, and a line then is defined by additionally choosing a polar angle. The variable along the line is then just the radius, and you can use ´numpy.linspace´ to discretize it. Doing so might also save time during calculation.

You can switch your coordinate system any time by using the bijective relation which is implemented e.g. [here](http://svn.gna.org/svn/relax/tags/1.3.16/maths_fns/coord_transform.py) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116658/faster-numpy-cartesian-to-spherical-coordinate-conversion).

Comment: Oh. How come I didn't think of that !? I was ready to do line equations in 3D ...
I'll update my code to use that, then accept your fine answer ! =)
Will you mind updating your answer with the specific code I'll have once I'm done ?

Comment: I'll do, but on the other hand you could also close this question and start new, more specific questions once you arrived there...

Comment: Oh, no, sorry, I meant only so that you'd have a complete answer (including specific code) for anyone interested later on ! =)

Comment: I put it in my updated answer in the end (looks great !). Thanks a bunch !